# Script does not enable unless I am in debug mode in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When I try to enable my interact script while debugging it works perfectly as long as I have one break point set. But when I run the game without debugging it fails to enable the script about about 50% of the time. Interact is the base class for NPC and MonsterAttack scripts. I only have NPC and MonsterAttack scripts attached to the physical game objects.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0) && !UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
    {

        if (interactedObject != null && interactedObject.GetComponent<Interact>() != null)
        {
            interactedObject.GetComponent<Interact>().enabled = false;
        }

        Interact.rotate = false;
        rayHit = GetInteraction();
   }
}

//Get interaction with clicked object
private RaycastHit GetInteraction()
{
    //Get the mouse clicked position
    Ray interactionRay = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit interactionInfo;


    if (Physics.Raycast(interactionRay, out interactionInfo, Mathf.Infinity))
    {
        Debug.DrawRay(interactionRay.origin, interactionInfo.point, Color.red);
        interactedObject = interactionInfo.collider.gameObject;

        if (interactedObject.tag != "NPC" && interactedObject.tag != "Monster")
        {
            //Move somewhere on the terrain
            playerAgent.stoppingDistance = 0f;
            playerAgent.SetDestination(interactionInfo.point);
        }
        else
        {
            //IT FAILS HERE
            interactedObject.GetComponent<Interact>().enabled = true; //<--------
            //Interact with an Object, NPC, Item, Monster
            interactedObject.GetComponent<Interact>().MovetoInteraction(playerAgent);
        }
    }
    return interactionInfo;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is compiling? Your first if statement in Update has no closing brace.

Comment: Yes i just missed the brace when editing the code to leave out the animation part of my code.

Comment: After a little bit of further testing I have found that it seems to be a problem with the raycast. For some reason it is picking up the terrain instead of the object I clicked on as if the raycast goes through the object and hits the terrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was actually because of my raycast. For some reason it is picking up the object and the terrain below it. So when I click on an object it sometimes uses the terrain instead of the object I clicked. Therefore the path that enables my script is not selected, which is the reason the script is not being enabled.